# How to load images from an NSURL with the imageNamed behaviour (@2x, ~ipad etc. variants)

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsurl

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` will do lots of clever things when loading files from the bundle, like caching to prevent multiple `UIImage` instances of the same image, looking for @2x and ~ipad suffixes, and setting the `scale` property correctly. I want to be able to do the same thing when loading images from the documents directory (specified with a `NSURL`). I've looked around but can't find anything in the docs for this, is there something I've missed?

I'm currently implementing this myself (the whole shebang, with caching, etc.) but I hate to duplicate framework code. I hope to get an answer before I'm done but if not I'll post the code.

Comment: This may be of some use: http://blog.mro.name/2010/11/high-res-uiimage-remote-load/

Comment: That doesn't do the behaviour I want - i.e. checking which files exist and falling back to other ones if they don't exist, and caching. Anyway, I ended up writing my own one (code posted in an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best thing I've come up with. It's not ideal as it's duplicating behaviour in the framework (perhaps with subtle inconsistencies), but it does the nice things we want from `imageNamed:`.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*)name relativeToURL:(NSURL*)rootURL
{
    // Make sure the URL is a file URL
    if(![rootURL isFileURL])
    {
        NSString* reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ only supports file URLs at this time.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException reason:reason userInfo:nil];
    }

    // Check the cache first, using the raw url/name as the key
    NSCache*    cache = objc_getAssociatedObject([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate, @"imageCache");
    // If cache doesn't exist image will be nil - cache is created later only if everything else goes ok
    NSURL*      cacheKey = [rootURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    UIImage*    image = [cache objectForKey:cacheKey];
    if(image != nil)
    {
        // Return the cached image
        return image;
    }

    // Various suffixes to try in preference order
    NSString*   scaleSuffix[] =
    {
        @"@2x",
        @""
    };
    CGFloat     scaleValues[] =
    {
        2.0f,
        1.0f
    };
    NSString*   deviceSuffix[] =
    {
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? @"~ipad" : @"~iphone",
        @""
    };
    NSString*   formatSuffix[] =
    {
        @"png"
    };
    NSURL*      imageURL = nil;
    CGFloat     imageScale = 0.0f;

    // Iterate through scale suffixes...
    NSInteger   ss, ssStart, ssEnd, ssInc;
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0f)
    {
        // ...forwards
        ssStart = 0;
        ssInc = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // ...backwards
        ssStart = (sizeof(scaleSuffix) / sizeof(NSString*)) - 1;
        ssInc = -1;
    }
    ssEnd = ssStart + (ssInc * (sizeof(scaleSuffix) / sizeof(NSString*)));
    for(ss = ssStart; (imageURL == nil) && (ss != ssEnd); ss += ssInc)
    {
        // Iterate through devices suffixes
        NSInteger ds;
        for(ds = 0; (imageURL == nil) && (ds < (sizeof(deviceSuffix) / sizeof(NSString*))); ds++)
        {
            // Iterate through format suffixes
            NSInteger fs;
            for(fs = 0; fs < (sizeof(formatSuffix) / sizeof(NSString*)); fs++)
            {
                // Add all of the suffixes to the URL and test if it exists
                NSString*   nameXX = [name stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@.%@", scaleSuffix[ss], deviceSuffix[ds], formatSuffix[fs]];
                NSURL*      testURL = [rootURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:nameXX];
                NSLog(@"testing if image exists: %@", testURL);
                if([testURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil])
                {
                    imageURL = testURL;
                    imageScale = scaleValues[ss];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If a suitable file was found...
    if(imageURL != nil)
    {
        // ...load and cache the image
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:imageScale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        NSLog(@"Image loaded, with scale: %f", image.scale);
        if(cache == nil)
        {
            cache = [NSCache new];
            objc_setAssociatedObject([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate, @"imageCache", cache, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
        [cache setObject:image forKey:cacheKey];
    }
    return image;
}
```

Please let me know if you find any problems. As far as I know the semantics are like `imageNamed:` - at least for the most common cases. Maybe there are a load of different image formats and some other modifiers I don't know about - the code should be fairly easy to modify to support that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do your trick, it's a simple test to check the scale of screen.

```
UIImage *image;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
  // @2x
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/images/yourImage@2x.png"];
  NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
} else {
  // @1x
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/images/yourImage.png"];
  NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

it has been answered here
[How should retina/normal images be handled when loading from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404410/how-should-retina-normal-images-be-handled-when-loading-from-url)

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but this is a different problem. Read how imageNamed: works and understand about how it caches images and how it looks for @2x, ~ipad suffixes, falling back to non-suffixed files if they are not present. Then re-read my question and you will understand. :)