# Do i need to return back the image dimensions for ios in json response?

Tags: ios, image, asp.net-web-api, image-resizing

I've built a website that stores images in 4 different sizes on the file system. It keeps the origional file size, medium, thumb, small image and resizes them as they upload.

We then created the web api to allow us to build the ios/android apps.

while building the apis our overseas developer then asked to provide the image dimensions along with the image file name. it took a lot of work regarding calculating the image sizes and saving them to the database.

```
{ "imagefilename" : "someimage.jpg", "LargeimageHeight" : "1000",  
"LargeimageWidth" : "500", "mediumImageHeight" : "500",
"mediumImageWidth" :       "250",
"smallImageHeight" : "100", "smallImageWidth" : "60" }
```

with the amount of image sections we have in the website made it a task and i want to know if this is really nessesary. Im not an ios developer but not really sure as to why the additioanl dimensions of the image need to be saved and or really needed.

i thought the ios has the image feature (@3x) (@2x) (@3x) ??

or do i use 1 specific folder image size for ios ??

does this always happen in the ios world for images that the code needs to know the image dimensions for the best result?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your iOS application show images in flow layout (like pinterest style) you must return image dimensions. Otherwise I don't think its nessesary

Comment: actually yes it was a pintrest style with a 2 column product listing. but that was only 1 section that used pinterest style. maybe we didn't need to do it for all the other apis. thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you need the return the image dimensions:

   - **Short answer: no.** You can load the image using `UIImage`, and call `image.size.height` and `image.size.width`.
   - **Long answer: maybe**, depending on the interface design of your application, and if every image has different dimensions, it might take a performance toll to load the image into memory before being able to get its size (and probably do autolayout and have it render on screen). You might have issues with scrolling speed, but it will depend on the specific design and requirements.
2. What is the `@2x` `@3x` iOS image feature

   iPhone and iPad screens come in different pixel densities (non-retina, retina and the retina iPhone 6+ screen). If you have a local image, stored on the phone, it can preload the image with the right scale automatically, by just providing the base name of the image, if you add the right suffix to each asset like `name@2x`, etc.

   Sadly, it **doesn't work the same for remote images** [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404410/how-should-retina-normal-images-be-handled-when-loading-from-url). You will have to check yourself for the scale and load the right image, or load one big file, and let it be resized on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider providing dimensions inside your API response.

**Think design:** 
When you scale your app to have many images at once, or when you distribute your app to multiple devices, you may realize the advantage. Your iphone 4 may end up downloading the image (worse, images) intended for iPhone 6S, and so on. If the reverse is true, it's even scary to think about.

How about the device asking for the image it's best suited for?

As for scaling of images, Bram De Geyter is correct - you can render whatever resides on the device, not fetch the correct one from the server. So having your API giving you the right dimensions is the only solution.

I have described the whole [image loading from API approach in my blog here](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-app-design-blog-load-images-asynchronously-inside-uitableview/).